# POST request does not work with fetch and React

Tags: reactjs, input, onclick, chakra-ui

Below is my code to send a post request with the data entered in a Chakra UI modal

```
function Create() {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  const [sku, setSku] = React.useState("");
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [unit, setUnit] = React.useState("");
  const handleChangesku = (event) => setSku(event.target.value);
  const handleChangeName = (event) => setName(event.target.value);
  const handleChangeUnit = (event) => setUnit(event.target.value);
  
  function handleClick() {
    fetch("/products", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        sku: sku,
        name: name,
        primary_unit: unit
      })
    }).then((res) => res.json());
    // Update the state with the received response
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onOpen}>Create Product</Button>

      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>Create Product</ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton />
          <ModalBody>
            <Text mb="8px">SKU</Text>
            <Input
              value={sku}
              onChange={handleChangesku}
              placeholder="SKU"
              size="sm"
            />
            <Text mb="8px">Name</Text>
            <Input
              value={name}
              onChange={handleChangeName}
              placeholder="Name"
              size="sm"
            />
            <Text mb="8px">Unit</Text>
            <Input
              value={unit}
              onChange={handleChangeUnit}
              placeholder="Unit"
              size="sm"
            />
          </ModalBody>

          <ModalFooter>
            <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3} onClick={handleClick}>
              Create
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

export default Create;
```

When I run this code nothing happens when I click on create in the modal. I get the following error when checking the network section of inspection panel:

```
0: {field: "sku", message: "This field is required"}
1: {field: "name", message: "This field is required"}
2: {field: "primary_unit", message: "This field is required"}
```

How can I fix this? I tried to use the hook UseCallback instead of just normal handleclick to change the values of the useState variables but it did not work. Do I necessarily need a form so that I can add an OnSubmit?

Comment: Have you tried setting the ContentType as JSON? And also is the endpoint expecting a JSON?

Comment: Yes, it is expecting a JSON, also setting ContentType did not work

Comment: Could you post the payload a CURL version of the request sent? In the Network tab of your browser DevTools click over the request and select 'Copy as CURL' and paste that in the updated question